# postgresql case inside function doesn't trigger

Tags: postgresql

So, i have a couple of functions inside my db.

One function needs to run when the data in a specific table is older than 5 minutes.

I've tried doing it with:

```
PERFORM case when now() - '5 minutes'::interval > (select end_time from x order by end_route desc limit 1) then update_x() else null end;
```

When i run the command as a regular select query, it runs OK. But when i put that inside another function (The one being called, returns updated table that is no older than 5 minutes), it never runs. Also, if i just put update_x(), then it runs OK (but every time the function is called).

Does anyone have any idea on how i could fix this?
One idea is to just set a cron to run the function every 5 mins independently, but i'd rather the server is idle since the function is quite resource intensive, and it doesn't get called that often.

I'm on version 8.4(Due to my ISP, so can't change, though i am considering moving to VPS, so if this is something that would work on 9.5 and newer, i can wait).

Comment: Hard to say without a bit more context, but one thing worth noting is that `now()` doesn't actually return the current time, but rather the start time of the current transaction. If this isn't what you want, try `clock_timestamp()` instead. See the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but once i moved the boolean up one level it started working.
So now instead of having perform case query inside function, i'm sending boolean to the function, and performing the check in a view above this function.

```
CREATE VIEW x_view AS select * from get_x((clock_timestamp() - '5 minutes'::interval)::timestamp > (select end_route from gps_skole2 order by end_route desc limit 1));
```

And inside the function:

```
PERFORM case when $1 then update_x() else null end;
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `now()` gives the start time of the current transaction and is invariable inside it. Use `clock_timestamp(),` example:

```
do $$
begin
    for i in 1..3 loop
        perform pg_sleep(1);
        raise notice 'now(): % clock_timestamp(): %', now(), clock_timestamp();
    end loop;
end $$;

NOTICE:  now(): 2017-12-06 10:22:40.422683+01 clock_timestamp(): 2017-12-06 10:22:41.437099+01
NOTICE:  now(): 2017-12-06 10:22:40.422683+01 clock_timestamp(): 2017-12-06 10:22:42.452456+01
NOTICE:  now(): 2017-12-06 10:22:40.422683+01 clock_timestamp(): 2017-12-06 10:22:43.468124+01
```

Per [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT)

> clock_timestamp() returns the actual current time, and therefore its value changes even within a single SQL command (...)
>
> now() is a traditional PostgreSQL equivalent to transaction_timestamp().

Comment: Doesn't work. i still don't get an update call. Works the same as now. If i run the command as a regular query, it updates, if i put it inside a function, it doesn't.

Comment: This is a guessing game without the complete code of both functions. Do you use `now()` in `update_x()`?

Comment: Managed to get it to work. i Use now() in multiple places, but update_x basically inserts new data into the table, and the check is whether the data in table x is older than 5 minutes. Thing is, update_x takes 30 seconds, so i wan't it to just take long on first query in 5 minutes interval, and then not trigger on consecutive queries inside web app.